# How to ask someone about my email

Tags: letter-writing

I recently received a reply from someone around two weeks ago stating that they would send me an email within a week as they were going overseas.  We were discussing a good time to call.

How would I word an email asking:

- What would be a good time to talk
- How his overseas trip went to New York.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

Hey John, Just checking if you've had time to send your email, how did your overseas trip go?

However, my idea sounds extremely inpolite and rude considering asking if he has had time.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I completely understand your concern.  I often read a reply in my head and ask myself if I were to be told this, how would I react.  I call it 'word-smithing'.  It is especially important in today's culture considering that body language can't be read over an email.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a cultural issue than one of diction, but your wording sounds perfectly polite to me.  I would correct the punctuation, capitalization, and spacing so it reads:

> Hey John,
>   Just checking if you've had time to send your email. How did your overseas trip go?

Answer (score 0):

If he sent the email, presumably you'd have gotten it.

How's this?

"I'm looking forward to receiving the email we discussed. Please call me at your convenience."

Or "Please let me know when a phone call will be convenient for you."